# How to enable tab completion of  wildcards in bash?

Tags: bash, wildcards, autocomplete

How can I enable tab completion in bash for a statement such as `vim db/migrate/*crea`?  Essentially I am looking for tab completion to match the regular expression and present the options.

How would one go about doing this?

This questions relates to one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607826/opening-a-db-migrate-file-more-effectively-wildcard-to-complete-the-beginning)

Comment: the expression `db/migrate/*crea` is not a regular expression. the `*` character here is used as a bash expansion wildcard.

Comment: Sure it's a regular expression.  It matches `db/migrate///////crea`.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

What version of bash are you using? For me with 4.1.2, it seems to work out of the box on CentOS 6.2:

```
[user@host foo]$ cd /tmp/foo
[user@host foo]$ mkdir bar
[user@host foo]$ touch bar/foo{1,2,3}
[user@host foo]$ vim bar/*1
*TAB*
[user@host foo]$ vim bar/foo1 
[user@host foo]$ touch bar/bar1
[user@host foo]$ vim bar/*1
*TAB* *TAB*
[user@host foo]$ vim bar/*1
bar1/ foo1
```

Are you making sure to tap TAB twice for the auto-completion list?

Comment: This has more to do with your Bash completion scripts than it has to do with your version of Bash.

Answer (score 1):

`show-all-if-ambiguous` makes pressing tab once (instead of twice) show all completions. It also changes the way globs are completed:

```
$ touch 1.0.{1,2}
$ bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous off'
$ open *0* # I pressed tab twice here, and *0* was kept as *0*
1.0.1  1.0.2
$ open *0*^C
$ bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
$ open *0* # I pressed tab once here, and *0* was replaced with 1.0.
1.0.1  1.0.2
$ open 1.0.
```

glob-complete-word (\eg) would also complete `*0` (without a wildcard at the end) to `1.0.`. It also works with patterns like `*/file*` and `**/file`.