# How do I let bash autocomplete wildcards?

Tags: bash, wildcards, autocomplete

If I have directory containing the files

```
foo.bar.a.cat
foo.bar.a.hat
```

and I type `ls f`+<kbd>TAB</kbd> the bash shell autocompletes to `ls foo.bar.a.`. If I type `ls *bar*`+ <kbd>TAB</kbd> I would like it to autocomplete to `*bar*.a.`. Is this possible?

This looks similar to the question

[How to enable tab completion of  wildcards in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37690/how-to-enable-tab-completion-of-wildcards-in-bash)

but the suggested answer, "it works out of the box for me", does not. I've also tried <kbd>TAB</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>, with no effect. The command ``bash --version`gives`GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want either:

#### insert-completions

<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> for 'insert all completions'

With this, a dir containing files name 'aa ab ac ad'
`ls a*` followed by `alt + *` would complete to `ls aa ab ac ad`

[Man page](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-insert_002dcompletions-_0028M_002d_002a_0029) entry on binding:

> insert-completions (M-*)
>
> Insert all completions of the text before point that would have been generated by possible-completions.

#### glob-expand-word

On some systems the above will not work with wildchars, the following does work on such systems for me:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd> (a two stroke combo)

Example:
I populated a dir with:

```
touch {a,b,c,d,e,f}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}00{a,b,c,d,f,e}
```

I then `ls *100*` followed by `ctrl + x, *`, which turns my readline into:

```
ls a100a a100b a100c a100d a100e a100f b100a b100b b100c b100d b100e b100f c100a c100b c100c c100d c100e c100f d100a d100b d100c d100d d100e d100f e100a e100b e100c e100d e100e e100f f100a f100b f100c f100d f100e f100f
```

[Man page](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-glob_002dexpand_002dword-_0028C_002dx-_002a_0029) entry for binding:

> glob-expand-word (C-x *)
>
> The word before point is treated as a pattern for pathname expansion, and the list of matching file names is inserted, replacing the word. If a numeric argument is supplied, a ‘*’ is appended before pathname expansion.

[Bash Ref Man Page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

Comment: This does not work (at least for me). Creating the files `touch aa ab ac ad` and typing `ls a` followed by `alt+*` gives the list, but doing it with `ls a*` does not. The wildcards are the point of the question.

Comment: @Hooked This works for me on `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` and `GNU bash, version 4.2.0(1)-release (x86_64--netbsd)` but not `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.2.0)`. And by worked, I mean it filed in the text. Will check my conf files to see if I have something extra.

Comment: That's strange, why would such a simple thing change from version to version? Any ideas on how to enable it or is it built-in at compile time?

Comment: @Hooked I'm a bit perplexed too... It also fails on my raspberry pi `GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)` (raspbian)

Comment: @Hooked Found alliterative binding which works on systems where the first had not, for me.

Comment: @Hooked check your `.inputrc` and /etc/inputrc` (or whatever files your readline is using).

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. Now that I know where to look (man page ref is extremely useful) I've found a similar answer on SuperUser http://superuser.com/questions/215950/how-to-expand-on-bash-command-line

Comment: Nice, apparently Alt-* works in OpenBSD ksh, mksh, etc (Ctrl-X,*  does not though, so Alt-* would be a more "portable" habit). Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this to ~/.inputrc:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

show-all-if-ambiguous makes pressing tab once (instead of twice) list all completions. It also makes the first tab press insert shared prefixes of glob expressions.

```
$ touch 1.0.{1,2}
$ echo *0* # I pressed tab once here
1.0.1  1.0.2
$ echo 1.0.
```

glob-complete-word (\eg) would also complete `*0` (without `*` at the end) to `1.0.`. It also completes for example `/System/Library/Launch*/*Finde` to `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist`.

If you wanted to convert `*` to `1.0.1 1.0.2` in the example above, use either insert-completions (\e*) or glob-expand-word (\C-x*).

Answer (score 6):

This problem is caused by bugs in the "bash-completion" package.

When the package is not installed bash does it's default completion, this is a pretty good generalised file name completion engine.

The "bash-completion" package is supposed to look at the rest of the line and be "smart" about the lists it generates. However, it's unable to duplicate the "glob" expansion successfully.

Personally, I think the package is trying far too hard and ends up being usable only by the "dumbest common user".

Though, before deleting it you may want to check the top of the file "/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion" for useful additions to your .bashrc for 'gross tuning' of the built-in bash completion.

BTW: It has over a hundred logged bugs ... https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?package=bash-completion

Comment: $ sudo yum erase bash-completion #fixed the issue for me