# Need bash glob to be expanded and keep it ready in the readline

Tags: bash, wildcards, readline

how can bash glob is expanded and keep the cursor ready on the readline so that keep current command from being executed

Comment: Have a look at `Programmable completion` in `man bash`, and see if that can be used for your purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I let bash autocomplete wildcards?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76592/how-do-i-let-bash-autocomplete-wildcards)